# when I run the program,I find the cursor can not move as I click in mQTextedit,

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class Example(QMainWindow):#这个是主界面。
    mySignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example,self).__init__()        
        self.initUI()    
        
    def initUI(self):#初始化第一界面
        #首先是标签：
 
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('一昔一奂')
        self.show()
        self.mySignal.connect(self.getValue_sm)#本身信号接收
        self.qt1 = mQTextEdit(self)
        self.qt1.resize(400, 550)
        self.qt1.setText('兔子，乌龟')
        self.qt1.move(200,55)#
        self.qt1.show()

    def getValue_sm(self,val):#这儿完全可以设定光标位置。
        print(val)


class mQTextEdit(QTextEdit):#这儿最好有个光标位置。
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, e4):
        #还需要在主窗口设置光标位置。从这里发送一个光标位置信息。
        b=0
        self.parent().mySignal.emit('44，ffa')#然后光标弄一下，就可以了，哈哈哈，
        tc=self.textCursor()
        tc.selectionStart()    #获取选中起始位置，实际上是点之前改变。先响应的是这个？
        tc.selectionEnd()
 
        print(tc.selectionStart(),tc.selectionEnd())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by overriding the mousePressEvent method and not invoking the base class method then you are eliminating the default behavior. The solution is:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, e4):
    super().mousePressEvent(e4)

    # 还需要在主窗口设置光标位置。从这里发送一个光标位置信息。
    b = 0
    self.parent().mySignal.emit("44，ffa")  # 然后光标弄一下，就可以了，哈哈哈，
    tc = self.textCursor()
    tc.selectionStart()  # 获取选中起始位置，实际上是点之前改变。先响应的是这个？
    tc.selectionEnd()

    print(tc.selectionStart(), tc.selectionEnd())
```

Comment: think,then how I can get the str before cursor.    es: 兔子,

Comment: @yypzq2019 I do not understand your language so it is difficult for me to help you, please try to do all the logic with the English language

Comment: def mousePressEvent(self, e4):
        super().mousePressEvent(e4)

        #还需要在主窗口设置光标位置。从这里发送一个光标位置信息。
        b=0
        self.parent().mySignal.emit('44，ffa')#然后光标弄一下，就可以了，哈哈哈，
        tc=self.textCursor()
        an=int(tc.selectionStart())
        print(an)#获取选中起始位置，实际上是点之前改变。先响应的是这个？
        tc.selectionEnd()
        wz=self.toPlainText()
        str=wz[0:an]
        print(str)  #      I get it ,think you.@eyllanesc

Comment: @yypzq2019 please avoid extended code in the comments, and most importantly avoid non English language, as it doesn't really allow us to understand what's written, and non latin characters make it even more difficult to read.